# construct triangle when given convergent sides bisectors

Tags: geometry

can anyone help me by using geometric transformations to solve this problem:
construct the triangle whose sides bisectors and their intersection point is given; my professor told me that if I assumed the problem to be solved I would notice that we have compositions such as symmetries, reflections, rotations . I can't really understand what he meant, if anyone can help me with a hint or the solution I would be very thankful

Answer (score 1):

Bisector intersection locates the circumcenter as per

$ \frac{a }{\sin A } = ... = ... 2 R $

So the entire triangle and circle can be rotated around circumcenter and reflected about a line through the center.

Comment: please sir can you give a full answer if you may, I am having problems grasping your idea